# flutter_sound 8.4.2 startPlayer() exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
 await _audioPlayer!.startPlayer(
    fromURI: 'https://URL/TestFiles/sssssssss.acc',
    codec: Codec.aacADTS,
  );
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

the exception is platform exceptio error unknown startplayer() error,null .
in the debug console I got these
FlutterSoundPlayer.log (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_player.dart:500:13

MethodChannelFlutterSoundPlayer.channelMethodCallHandler (package:flutter_sound_platform_interface/method_channel_flutter_sound_player.dart:161:19

I am using real android device
flutter doctor returns everything is good
this remote file works well in angular client

Answer (score 1):

It's played Now I was missing that the file extension is aac not acc

so it should be

```
await _audioPlayer!.startPlayer(
fromURI: 'https://URL/TestFiles/sssssssss.aac',
);
} catch (e) {
print(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to play audios i use this library
audioplayers: ^0.19.1
declare this variable to access audio

```
 String audioCorrect = "audio/access_granted.mp3";
 String audioInCorrect = "audio/access_denied.mp3";
```

method for init player

```
void initPlayer() {
    advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);
  }
```

call initPlayer in initState method
play the audio this way

```
   audioCache.play(audioCorrect);
```

Comment: flutter sound plugin has method startPlayer() to play audioes
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Q5c-E63kfI&t=317s

Comment: with audio player the start method you only pass the url of where the audio file is